# Javascript mouse event, drag and drop an image item in the html page

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I am using MacBook Pro and mouse is touchpad. I do not use physical mouse.

I am now exercising Javascript events programming. I suppose to make a toolbar, then I could drag and drop image item using Javascript mouse event. I wrote codes as below. Currently, I only implement the ball image could listen to mouse event. My purpose is to select the ball, then a new ball image could be created and put to the place where mouse is moved and released. I could create multiple balls and moved to the body of html page wherever I want.

The following codes could not invoke mouseup events. And the ball sticks to the mouse and could not be released/unattached.

Any help and hints?

Thanks in advance!

[image: ball.jpeg]
[image: soccer-gate.jpeg]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Drag image item from toolbar</p>
  <table><tr><td>
                 <img src="soccer-gate.jpeg" id="gate">
             </td>
             <td>  
                 <img src="ball.jpeg" id="ball">
             </td>
         </tr>
  </table>  
  
  <script>

    ball.onmousedown = function(event) {
      var ball_temp = document.getElementById("ball");;
      var ball_clone = ball_temp.cloneNode(true);
      ball_clone.id = "ball_clone";

      let shiftX = event.clientX - ball_clone.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      let shiftY = event.clientY - ball_clone.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log("event client X,Y is ",event.clientX,event.clientY); 
       

      ball_clone.style.position = 'absolute';
      ball_clone.style.zIndex = 1000;
      document.body.append(ball_clone);

      function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
        ball_clone.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        ball_clone.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
        console.log("pageX,pageY is ", pageX,pageY);        
      }

      function onMouseMove(event) {
        console.log("mouse move");
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
      }
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    };

    ball.onmouseup = function(event) {
        console.log("remove mousemove event")
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    };
    document.addEventListener('mouseup',onmouseup);

    ball.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to say the truth, I wrote codes by reference a book. And I modify the codes and there are bugs. I use chatGPT finally fix my bugs.

There are two mistakes in original codes. onmouseup shall not be ball.onmouseup, and also this function should be inside onmousedown function.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Drag image item from toolbar</p>
  <table><tr><td>
                 <img src="soccer-gate.svg" id="gate">
             </td>
             <td>  
                 <img src="ball.svg" id="ball">
             </td>
         </tr>
  </table>  
  
  <script>
  ball.onmousedown = function(event){
    var ball_temp = document.getElementById("ball");;
    var ball_clone = ball_temp.cloneNode(true);
    ball_clone.id = "ball_clone";
        
    let shiftX = event.clientX - ball_clone.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    let shiftY = event.clientY - ball_clone.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log("event client X,Y is ",event.clientX,event.clientY); 
        
    ball_clone.style.position = 'absolute';
    ball_clone.style.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.append(ball_clone);   
        
    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
      ball_clone.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
      ball_clone.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
      console.log("pageX,pageY is ", pageX,pageY);  
      console.log("event.clientX,event.clientY is ", event.clientX, event.clientY);
      console.log("ball_clone.getBoundingClientRect().left,ball_clone.getBoundingClientRect().top is ", ball_clone.getBoundingClientRect().left,ball_clone.getBoundingClientRect().top);
      console.log("shiftX,shiftY is",shiftX,shiftY);
      console.log("ball_clone.style.left,ball_clone.style.top is",ball_clone.style.left,ball_clone.style.top);           
    }
        
    function onMouseMove(event) {
      console.log("mouse move");
      moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        
  
    onmouseup = function(event) {
      console.log("remove mousemove event")
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    };
    document.addEventListener('mouseup',onmouseup);
        
    ball.ondragstart = function() {
      return false;
    };
  } 
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```